# Developer role not able to push to unprotected branches in Gitlab

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab

I am new to gitlab. I have successfully created unprotected branches dev & design with master role in project testapp with the following commands:

```
git checkout -b dev 
git checkout -b design
```

Then I push all the files successfully to both branches.

Later on I run the following command to make my branches remotely :

```
git branch dev 
git branch design
```

Now the issue is, my team member whom I have added in project with developer role is not able to list out branches dev & design and also not able to push to those branches. He try to push with following commands:

```
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin dev
```

Please list the steps for me.
Thanks

Comment: Those last 3 commands should be executed by `you`. These add the branches to the remote tracker. Without that, they'll never see the branch and cant push to it. You can also do `git push --all -u` to push all of your local branches to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your teammate needs to run the `checkout` command to track the remote branches.  Whether or not he has local `dev/design` branches, he just needs to associate them with their corresponding remote branches.  This is done by creating a [tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches):

> Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship
>   to a remote branch.

To create new tracking branches locally, you can use the shorthand:

```
git checkout dev
git checkout design
```

Where the general form is:

```
git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]
```

E.g.

```
git checkout --track origin/dev
git checkout --track origin/design
```

Or, if you'd would rather turn an existing local branch into a tracking branch, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch).